# jquery draggable: gets jumpy when you click on the draggable handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-1.9

Did any come across this buggy thingy with jquery `draggable` before when you add `right: 0; bottom: 0;` to your popup box?

The box **jumps** away from your cursor when you **click on** the `handler`

jquery,

```
$(".popup").draggable({ 
cursor: "move",
handle: ".popup-outer",
cancel: ".popup-inner"
});
```

html,

```
<div class="popup-outer popup">
    <div class="popup-inner">
        <div class="box-close"><a href="#" class="button-close">x close</a></div>
        <div class="ajax-response"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css,

```
.popup-outer{
    position:absolute;

    top:0;
    left:0;
    right: 0; //this causes the bug
    bottom: 0; //this causes the bug

    max-width: 1000px;
    height:500px;
    margin: auto;

    padding:6px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius: 4px; 
    background: url(../image/trans_black.png);
}

.popup-inner {
    text-align:left; 
    background-color:#ffffff; 
    margin:0px; 
    padding:20px;
    overflow:hidden; 
    -moz-border-radius:2px;
    -webkit-border-radius:2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border:0px solid #999;
    color:#333333;

    border:0 solid red;

    cursor:default;
}
```

any idea how can I fix it?

Comment: tealou my answer not working for your requirement ?

Comment: not working at all. thanks.

Comment: What is your requirement ?

Comment: Are you tried my link http://jsfiddle.net/cNmSM/4/ ?

Comment: you did mistakes in that code. if you try to remove `//this causes the bug` from your css then you see what happens. thanks.

Comment: `//` is not part of css!!